# find case insensitive records using find_all in ruby

Tags: ruby

I need records to be fetched from a csv from multiple rows using the `find_all` method

Consider a csv having records of `Employee` & `Manager` names.

```
@csv_table = CSV.parse(data, headers: true)
@results = @csv_table.find_all { |row| row['Employee'].start_with? @text }
```

I'm able to find only the records in `Employee` column but don't know how to search from both the `Employee` & `Manager` columns and also with the case insensitive condition

Answer (score 2):

The both Employee & Manager match in solved with a double condition in the block :

```
@results = @csv_table.find_all do |row|
  row['Employee'].start_with? @text || row['Manager'].start_with? @text
end
```

The insensitive problem could be solved in 2 ways : by downcasing (or upcasing) each string compared :

```
searchable_text = @text.downcase
@results = @csv_table.find_all do |row|
  row['Employee'].downcase.start_with? searchable_text ||
    row['Manager'].downcase.start_with? searchable_text
end
```

Or in a more elegant way with a insensitive regex :

```
regex = /^#{@text}/i # notice the ^ to mimic the start_with?
@results = @csv_table.find_all do |row|
  row['Employee'].match? regex || row['Manager'].match? regex
end
```

Depending on the content, the regex may behave slightly differently from `start_with?`, but for names it should be OK.

Comment: You could write: `select_headers = ['Employee', 'Manager']; ....find_all do |row| select_headers.any? { |header| header[row].match? regex }`. That way you need only change `select_headers` if they were to change.